# Can pansies overwinter in Central PA?

Tags: overwintering

If I plant pansies among bushes in my landscaping, will they come back the next spring? I live in Central PA.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they will overwinter. I am in south eastern PA and do this often. It works best if you start with small plants. They sometimes almost seem to disappear in winter, but invariably come back in spring. On some mild winters, they may bloom steadily throughout the winter.

Comment: With sufficient and continuous snow cover or an insulating mulch, pansies will winter over in Minnesota (USDA zone 4).